# My website is showing as "deceptive site ahead" on shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

My website is showing as "deceptive site ahead" in the browsers.

My website is on shopify. I'm not sure how to backup, scan or download my website files and remove whatever is causing the problem.

[image]

Comment: First, if you don't tell us the URL, nobody will be able to help you. Second, this does not seem to be a programming problem in the first place, so the question might be not appropriate here.

Comment: You are following a link to a mis-configured App for example. If the SSL certificate is not from an approved CA, you'll see this message. This has ZERO to do with Shopify as Shopify ensures its SSL is correctly functioning. So you should figure out if this is your App, how to do SSL correctly.